# Truncate load in Redshift daily

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Would like some suggestions on loading data to Redshift.
Currently we have an EMR cluster where RAW data is ingested regularly. We have a transformation job which runs daily and creates final modeled object. However, we are following truncate and load strategy in EMR . Due to business reasons there is no way to figure out which data has changed.

We are planning to store of this modeled object in Redshift.

> Now my question is If we follow the same truncate and load strategy in
> RedShift also, will that work?

I was able to find only articles which say use copy if you want to perform bulk copy, and then use insert command for small updates. But nothing on can and should we be using RedShift where the data is getting overwritten daily.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what you have in mind.  You intend, once per day, to wipe the cluster of all data, load all new data from fresh, and then use that data until the next wipe/load.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. 80% of the tables will be wiped and some 20%  tables where we are able to capture the change in data we would perform an update/merge

Comment: How much data will you be loading after a wipe, roughly speaking?  also, what are you thinking to do about `VACUUM` for your update/merge tables?

Comment: Mostly will schedule a vacuum command after load is completed for all the tables. Regarding the size of data to be loaded daily, my guess it would be several TB. It would be ~500 tables and ~100 TB.

Comment: Can you clarify with regard to data size - "several TB" is quite different to "~100 TB".

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I went back and checked the DB, it will be ~5TB. so my earlier  number was totally wrong.